# Using the variation of parameters method to find the particular integral of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE:
$$ x(x+1)y^{''} + (2-x^{2})y^{'} - (2+x)y = 0 $$
Given in the question were two sollutions to the associated homogeneous equation, which were $y_{1} = \frac{1}{x}$ and $y_{2} = e^{x}$. By the variation of parameters method, we're then asked to find the particular integral. I started by finding the wronksian of $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$:
$$W(y_{1},y_{2}) = \frac{e^{x}}{x^{2}}(1+x)$$
I then found the two functions $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ for a particular integral of the form $y_{PI} = y_{1}u_{1} + y_{2}u_{2}$. I  found $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$  to be:
$$u_{1}(x) = -\frac{1}{4}x^{4} - \frac{1}{3}x^{3} + c$$
$$u_{2}(x) = -e^{-x}(x^2 + 3x + 3) + d $$
I then used this to find the particaular integral, which I got as:
$$y_{PI} = -\frac{1}{4}x^3 - \frac{4}{3}x^2 - 3x - 3 + \frac{c}{x} + de^x $$
However, when I sub this back into the ODE, the resulting expression doesn't equal $(1+x)^2$, and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.
Thanks in advance for any advice/help

Comment: So your right hand side of the ODE is $(1+x)^2$?

Comment: You have to divide both sides by the first coefficient $x(x+1)$, then start doing what you have done. This procedure only works for the standard form $y''+py'+qy=0$.

Comment: So, if I were to divide by $x(x+1)$, would the resulting particular integral be found in a similar way, but with the RHS now equal to $\frac{x+1}{x}$? Thanks

Comment: I will look at it.

Comment: (I'd made a sign error)